# JQxRadioButton color is not working

Tags: jquery

How to set up color of `jqxRadioButton`?

I am trying to set `color` and `bgcolor` attribute in HTML but no success.
It looks like color for this component is not manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [jqWidgets](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxcheckandradio/jquery-radiobutton-styling-and-appearance.htm) documentation.

> To apply your custom style to jqxRadioButton, you need to set its
>   `'theme'` property(option) to point to your theme name string.

**Example:**

```
$("#jqxradiobutton").jqxRadioButton({ theme: 'summer', width: 120, height: 25 });
```

**<kbd>[Read More](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxcheckandradio/jquery-radiobutton-styling-and-appearance.htm)</kbd>**

Comment: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxcheckandradio/jquery-radiobutton-styling-and-appearance.htm - Look at this. There is a working sample. Follow the same approach to get the same results